# Is it investigation or investigations?

Tags: grammatical-number

The sentence is about someone who researched more about a old notebook.

> I did some more investigation/s about it.

Is investigation or investigations right and why?

Comment: How many did you do?

Comment: More idiomatic would be "I did some more investigating."

Comment: If all the investigating is happening around the same time, it's one investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, *investigation* (like *research*) is uncountable, and so I would use the singular.

Like many uncountable nouns, it can be used countably, to mean "instances of investigation". So if you for some reason wanted to think of, and express, your work as several separate activities, you could say *investigations*.

As @DjinTonic says in a comment, *do investigation* is not idiomatic. *Investigate*, or *do some investigating* are better. If you want to use *investigations*, then *carry out* is the best verb to use; but *I carried out some more investigation* sounds rather formal.

Answer (score 0):

A Google Books search shows "some investigation" and "some investigations" are both used, although there are several other ways of phrasing this, as other comments and answers note. Examples tend to be from judicial and legislative inquiries.

You might intuit that "I did some investigation" suggests a bit less effort than "I did some investigations", but it's hard to prove that.

Singular:

"did some investigation" crops up several times in the US Congressional record. For example: "I did some investigation with regard to the case". *Internal Revenue Investigation*, US Congressional Committee testimony, 1953. "You did some investigation that your Mayor O'Dwyer made you stop..." *Investigation of Organized Crime in Interstate Commerce*, 1950. "I did some investigation here." *Presidential Campaign Expenditures*, 1928.

There is some use in fiction: "'Well, the organization was lucky,' Vandeik said, 'but I believe they also did some investigation beforehand. ...'" *The Future Happens Twice: The Perennial Project*, Matt Browne, 2007

And a social science book, "I also did some investigation of RSU's TRIO program." *The Burden of Academic Success: Managing Working-Class Identities in College*, Allison L. Hurst, 2010.

Plural:

Again in Congressional reports: "They did some investigations" occurs several times. For instance "They did some investigations." as a standalone sentence in *Serious Management Problems at the National Archives...*, 1992. "Last year we did some investigations by stopping trucks coming into the city from New Jersey in particular" *Waste Oil Recovery*, 1982.

And in the UK "You, yourself, as a journalist, also did some investigations, including talking to other journalists?" Quoted in *Diana Inquest: The Untold Story*. John Morgan, 2009.

"Anne found out about this when she did some investigations inside the compound immediately north of the church" *San Antonio Missions National Historical Park: A Commitment to Research*, Gilberto R. Cruz, 1983.

"We did some investigations with another group up here at a graveyard" *Ghost Hunters of New England*, Allan Brown, 2008